# file search policy for FileReader if I use hyphen in path

Tags: java, io, path, filepath, filenotfoundexception

lets research three different code lines:

### line 1:

```
    System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/nio_data.txt")).readLine());
```

output:

```
one
```

### line 2:

change `nio_data` with `nio-data`

```
System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/nio-data.txt")).readLine());
```

output:

```
null
```

### line 3:

```
System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/nioSOMETGING_WRONGdata.txt")).readLine());
```

output:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: data\nioSOMETGING_WRONGdata.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Can you explain this difference?

snippet 2 is very surprising for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Eclipse bug.

In Idea last two lines lead to `FileNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Tried again with creating nio_data.txt file

The first one (correct path) printed 'one' the only thing in the file.

However I still got FNFE for the second two. Perhaps it's something with your exceptions.

Comment: I have file at this path "data/nio_data.txt"

Comment: I have one line in main. Which exceptions can happened ?

Answer (score 0):

i suppose there is a bug.?
You should try the full path 
for example your file is at c:/data/nio_data.txt

you should try this

```
System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data\nio_data.txt")).readLine());
```

or

```
System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data\\nio_data.txt")).readLine());
```

Comment: You need to double your "\" characters. You do not need to double your "/" characters.

Comment: For absolute paths I see same behaviour in Eclipse